# Marshmallow field set to another field's value if missing

Tags: python, marshmallow

I have something like this:

```
class TimeoutSettings(StrictSchema):
    general_timeout = fields.Int(required=True)
    build_timeout = fields.Int(default='I donno')
```

Is there any way that I can set `build_timeout` to `general_timeout`, only when `build_timeout` itself is missing?

Answer (score 1):

could be achieved using [`post_load`](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html#marshmallow.decorators.post_load)